# Maven Settings File: not resolving profile properties

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have the following settings.xml file and I expect the mirror.url to be replaced by the property defined in the profile when calling **mvn clean install** but it is not, any idea why?

```
<settings>
    <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
            <id>publicGroupProxy</id>
            <name>Proximity mirrored central repository in group public</name>
            <url>${mirror.url}</url>
        </mirror>
    </mirrors>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <properties>
                <mirror.url>https://example.com/content/groups/public</mirror.url>
                <repo.url>https://example.com/repository/content/groups/public</repo.url>
            </properties>
            <id>production-repositories</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>production-repository</id>
                    <url>${repo.url}</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>production-repository</id>
                    <url>${repo.url}</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>production-repositories</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

logs:

```
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata .../maven-metadata.xml from/to publicGroupProxy (${mirror.url}): Cannot access ${mirror.url} wit
h type default using the available connector factories: BasicRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

I tried executing mvn clean install but mirror.url wasn't replaced by the property defined in the profile.